# How can I get getline(variable, n) to run only if the input file does contain another value to be read?

Tags: c++

I realize the question may be kind of weirdly worded, but allow me to explain myself better. The input file may contain multiple lines which consist of 6 grades... or a minimum of 5 grades.

So a file may look like this:

```
90 85 72 95 83 96
97 69 29 0 39 69
```

And my code works perfectly when there are 6 grades in each line.

```
while(!fin.eof())
{
    fin.getline(student[student_count].grade1, 4, ' ');
    fin.getline(student[student_count].grade2, 4, ' ');
    fin.getline(student[student_count].grade3, 4, ' ');
    fin.getline(student[student_count].grade4, 4, ' ');
    fin.getline(student[student_count].grade5, 4, ' ');
    fin.getline(student[student_count].grade6, 4);

    ...
}
```

This crashes though whenever the file has 5 grades in a line, which does make sense. Example:

```
90 85 72 95 83 
97 69 29 0 39 69
```

I can't think of a way to avoid this. I was thinking of a try statement, but I can't seem to make it work.

Additional info: The files do contain a name and last name before the grade, so I can't count the number of characters in each line to solve the problem. Since a name with a very short name could become a problem if I were to say if chars < 10 or something.

NOTE: I am not allowed to use the string library...

Answer (score 0):

You could try some thing like ,

```
std::string linefromfile = "90 85 72 95 83"; // parse and save the line here
std::istringstream buffer( linefromfile );
std::string token;

while( std::getline( buffer, token, ' ' ) ) // split the value with whitesaces
{
    std::cout << token << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I actually cannot use the string library. :( I just included that important note in the original post.